# Как на странице вариабельного товара woocommerce вывести в модальном окне актуальную цену?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет-магазин на **wordpress+woocommerce** в котором имеются вариабельные товары.
Мне нужно получить актуальную цену на странице товара в зависимости от выбранной опции и вывести в модальное окно.
Вопрос именно в выводе актуальной цены с опцией, т.к. `$product->get_price()` выводит только базовую цену

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'slon_after_add_to_cart_btn' );

function slon_after_add_to_cart_btn(){
    global $product;
    echo '<div>'.$product->get_price()'.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вариативных товаров есть скрытое поле variation_id в который записывается id вариации при выборе вариации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После изменения вариации можно отправлять ajax запросс и уже обработчике получать актуальную цену через

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id ); 
$price = $product->get_price();
```

**ИЛИ** можно использовать action 'found_variation' который возвращает цену вариации в объекте data

```
$( '.variations_form' ).on( 'found_variation', function( e, data ) {
    console.log(data);
} );
```